# android intro screen error when add to 8 screen, but not error if 4 screen

Tags: android

Android intro screen error. I try to add some screen to intro screen but after I add some screen it's be error when I slide the fifth screen but until fourth screen it work normally.

How i can fix this?
This is my code:

```
package com.emergency.e_place;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnSkip, btnNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Making notification bar transparent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


        // layouts of all welcome sliders
        // add few more layouts if you want
        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.welcome_slide1,
                R.layout.welcome_slide2,
                R.layout.welcome_slide3,
                R.layout.welcome_slide4,
                R.layout.welcome_slide4,
                R.layout.welcome_slide4,
                R.layout.welcome_slide4,
                R.layout.welcome_slide4};

        // adding bottom dots
        addBottomDots(0);

        // making notification bar transparent
        changeStatusBarColor();

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

        btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = getItem(+1);
                if (current < layouts.length) {
                    // move to next screen
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                } else {
                    launchHomeScreen();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];
        int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        finish();
    }

    //  viewpager change listener
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            addBottomDots(position);

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                // last page. make button text to GOT IT
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // still pages are left
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };

    /**
     * Making notification bar transparent
     */
    private void changeStatusBarColor() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * View pager adapter
     */
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Logcat output

```
07-18 15:15:35.048 383-383/com.emergency.e_place E/AndroidRuntime: 
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.emergency.e_place, PID: 383
        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
            at com.emergency.e_place.HelpActivity.addBottomDots(HelpActivity.java:101)
            at com.emergency.e_place.HelpActivity.access$400(HelpActivity.java:21)
            at com.emergency.e_place.HelpActivity$3.onPageSelected(HelpActivity.java:121)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1794)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:569)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:553)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2103)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8132)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2149)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2431)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2164)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2431)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2164)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2431)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2164)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2431)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2164)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2431)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2164)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2431)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2164)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2292)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1622)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2543)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2240)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8340)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4612)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4478)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4036)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4090)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4059)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4170)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4067)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4227)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4036)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4090)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4059)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4067)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4036)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6328)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6277)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6248)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6213)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6408)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java
```

Comment: pass `dots.length-1` in your for loop in `addBottomDots` function

Comment: there's no dots.length-1 in addBottomDots

Comment: Maybe your int arrays are shorter than 8.

Comment: @mvai no, there's no code for that

Comment: Yes, you call colorsInactive[currentPage] and colorsActive[currentPage] with currentPage up to 7. Anyway, just go to line 101 of your file and see where the error is.

Comment: it's the error `dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);`

Comment: how many colors/entries does  `colorsInactive` have?

Comment: @SripadRaj oh yeah just have 4 color

Comment: So the error says you have only 4 entries and you're trying to access 5th entry which is not there. So your program crashes. Try passing `dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage-1]);`